# "Deep-copy" of Swift dictionary with map()?

Tags: swift, dictionary, swift2, gameplay-kit

I have a `GKGameModel` that stores its internal state in an array `a` of `Card`s and a dictionary `b` that maps from `Int`s to arrays of `Card`s. GameplayKit mandates that I must copy this internal state in [`setGameModel:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKGameModel_Protocol/index.html).

The following code is meant to [just-copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812433/swift-how-do-i-make-a-exact-duplicate-copy-of-an-array) the array and "deep-copy" the dictionary. FWIK this should be sufficient since `Card`s themselves never change.

```
var a: [Card]
var b: [Int: [Card]]

func setGameModel(gameModel: GKGameModel) {
    let otherGameModel = gameModel as! GameModel
    a = otherGameModel.a
    b = otherGameModel.b.map { (i: Int, cards: [Card]) in (i, cards) }
}
```

However, this causes the following syntax error in the line that attempt the "deep-copy":

> Cannot assign a value of type '[(Int, [Card])]' to a value of type
>   '[Int, [Card]]'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: My Swift's a bit rusty when it comes to literals, but like vadian said, this `(i: Int, cards: [Card]) in (i, cards)` defines an array but you want a dictionary which would use the other brackets: `[i: Int, cards: [Card]] in [i, cards]`. Syntax may not be correct but the issue is something along that line ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case:

```
b = otherGameModel.b
```

is sufficient.

Because, [`Array` and `Dictionary` are both value types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-ID93). So when it is assigned to another variable, it will be *deep* copied.

```
var bOrig: [Int: [Int]] = [1: [1,2,3], 2:[2,3,4]]
var bCopy = bOrig

bCopy[1]![2] = 30

bOrig[1]![2] // -> 3
bCopy[1]![2] // -> 30
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message reveals there is a type mismatch:

variable `b` is declared as `Dictionary<Int,[Card]>` but the map function returns an `Array` of `tuplets (Int, [Card])`

Comment: So can this be solved with `map()` or is there a better alternative?

Comment: No, because a `Dictionary` does not respond to `map()`. You might use an enumerator.

Comment: I'll try this replacement for the offending line: `b = [:]; for (i, cards) in otherGameModel.b { hands[i] = cards }`