# Copy a static variable with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, static, uicollectionview

I use this code to adapt the model of a collection view. The problem is that when I modify the *model* variable, it also modify the *originalModel* variable because it's static which is not my intention. I want to keep the originalModel variable static but just copy it's content in the *model* variable

```
class Helper{
  static var originalModel: [MyModel]? =  nil 

  static func modifyDataSourceBigView () -> [MyModel]? {
    if let model = originalModel {
      //model.removeAtIndexPath
      // Some other staff to adapt the model
      return model
    }
  }

  static func modifyDataSourceSmallView () -> [MyModel]? {
    if let model = originalModel {
      //model.removeAtIndexPath
      // Some other staff to adapt the model
      return model
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem occur because array `[MyModel]` contains references to `MyModel` objects. Your functions return you *copies* of `originalModel`, that contains references to *original* `MyModel` objects. You have two ways to fix your issue:

1. Declare `MyModel` as `struct`, not `class`, and it instances will be passed by value, not by reference;
2. Perform copy object methods, for example make `MyModel` conform to `NSCopying` and implement `copyWithZone()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your static array like below. But it won't be deep copy, if you would like to deep copy your array of objects just refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812433/how-do-i-make-a-exact-duplicate-copy-of-an-array).

```
class Helper {

    static var originalModel: [MyModel]? =  nil

    static func modifyDataSourceBigView () -> [MyModel]? {
        if var model = originalModel{
            model.remove(at: 0)
            // Some other staff to adapt the model
            return model                
        }

        return nil
    }

    static func modifyDataSourceSmallView () -> [MyModel]? {
        if var model = originalModel {
            model.remove(at: 0)
            // Some other staff to adapt the model
            return model
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```