# Using copy in Anyhashable in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift. I have a mutable dictionary where I need to do a copy on it. I have the code in Objective-C and when I try to convert that to Swift it says Value of type [AnyHashable] has no member 'copy'. Can someone help me convert below ObjC code to Swift 4.

This is the original Objective-C code:

```
NSMutableArray *months = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

NSDictionary *monthDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:@[[months copy]] forKeys:@[@"values"]];
```

Below is what I am trying when converting to Swift 4:

```
var months = [AnyHashable]()

var monthDictionary = [AnyHashable: Any](objects: [months.copy()], forKeys: ["values"])
```

Cannot use 'copy' here.

Comment: see this , it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812433/how-do-i-make-a-exact-duplicate-copy-of-an-array

Comment: What types of data is the months? In Swift, both arrays and dictionaries are value types, so depending on what a "month" is, you might not need to explicitly copy them.

Comment: Which type is `months` supposed to contain? Don't try to translate ObjC to Swift literally? In most cases there are better native APIs.

Comment: months is NsmutableArray

Comment: I can see that `months` is `NSMutableArray`. My question was what **static** type does the array **contain**? Swift is based on a strong type system.

Comment: It contains Strings.12 months from January to December.