# Array to Array copy

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have two arrays. One is:

```
var array = [[String]]()
```

The second one is:

```
var finalArray = NSMutableArray()
```

`array` is blank.

I want to copy all the data from the final array to array.
For these two different types of array, direct this code won't work.

```
array = finalArray
```

Comment: Don't use `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` in Swift.

Comment: You can't directly assign different types array to like this here your first array is **[[String]]** type so you need to convert finalArray elements to that type and then you can assign or add elements in that array

Comment: see this for [help1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27812433/how-do-i-make-a-exact-duplicate-copy-of-an-array) and [help2](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/deep-copy-vs-shallow-copy-and-how-you-can-use-them-in-swift-c623833f5ad3/)

Comment: I guess in your actual question, you have stated that the data type of your array is [String]. But after edit, it is now looks like [[String]] in the question. It seems like a typo in the edit.

Answer (score 1):

An `NSArray` can be converted to a Swift array of a given element type with the `as?` operator, like so:

```swift
array = finalArray as? [[String]] ?? []
```

Note that we have to use the conditional typecast operator `as?` because it's not known at compile-time whether `finalArray` actually is an array of string arrays (since `NSArray` does not use generics in Swift).